# Compute the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just as the title says, how to compute the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{n!}$

Comment: Quasi-immediate if you split $n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

$$=-\dfrac{(-1)^0}{0!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}-e^{-1}$$

$$=-1+e^{-1}-e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=xe^x$. Then (that is your turn !):

$f'(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n (n+1)}{n!}$.

Can you proceed ?